# Vim - make comment shortcut

Tags: vim, comments

I often write LaTeX using Vim. And I have been taught that one can comment a number of selected lines (in visual mode) using the following command:

```
:'<,'>s!^!%!
```

And similarly, one may uncomment lines in visual mode by using this command:

```
:'<,'>s!^%!!
```

Here, '%' denotes the commenting symbol for LaTeX. But I would very much like to make a shortcut to make it easier for myself to use these commands. For instance a keybinding or some sort of function so that I do not have to remember this syntax. How does one do that?

Comment: It'd be easier to use a commenter plugin for vim that can handle multiple types.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)

Answer (score 4):

First, there are several commenter plugins, that do this very well, and those are generic (and often extensible) so that they work for any filetype, not just Latex:

- [NERD Commenter plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [tComment plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)
- [commentary.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3695)

are just a few popular plugins.

#### Custom mapping

That said, it's a good learning experience to develop a mapping on your own. Here's how:

First, mappings are just instructions that when certain key(s) are pressed, Vim translates them into other keys (on the right-hand side). Your mapping is for *visual mode*, so the command is `:vmap`. What do you normally do? You select the lines to be commented, and press `:`; Vim automatically inserts the `'<,'>` for you. You write the `:s` command, and conclude by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Translation:

```
vmap <Leader>c :s!^!%!<CR>
```

The `<Leader>` is a configurable, unused key, defaulting to backslash. So, your mapping is invoked by pressing <kbd>\</kbd> and then <kbd>C</kbd>. Put that into your `~/.vimrc` to make it permanent, and you're done. *Wait! There's more.*

#### Advanced mappings

First, [you should use `:vnoremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Second, that mapping is global, but it applies only to the Latex *filetype*. So, it should apply only to Latex *buffers*; there's the `<buffer>` modifier for that.

You can define that for certain filetypes by prepending `:autocmd Filetype tex ...`, and put that into your `~/.vimrc`. But that gets unwieldy as you add mappings and other settings for various filetypes. Better put the commands into `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex_mappings.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

```
vnoremap <buffer> <Leader>c :s!^!%!<CR>
```

Technically, you should use `<LocalLeader>` instead of `<Leader>`. They default to the same key, but the distinction allows to use a different prefix key for buffer-local mappings (only if you need / like).

Let's add the alternative mapping for uncommenting, triggered via <kbd>\</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>:

```
vnoremap <buffer> <LocalLeader>c :s!^!%!<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <LocalLeader>C :s!^%!!<CR>
```

Note that you could combine both into one, using `:help sub-replace-expression` with a conditional expression. If anything here is over your head, don't worry. You should be using one of the mentioned plugins, anyway :-)

Comment: Tangentially related but important: comment plugins work well if the `comments` option is set appropriately for the current filetype.  When it isn't, they break.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Well, at least NERD Commenter has definitions for more than 300 filetypes built-in (and only uses `'comments'` as a fallback).